# Incorrect page saved for visits on the index page

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We have two nopcommerce shops running on pretty much the same code. Both of those have GA handled through GTM with more or less the same code, however for some reason on one of those two shops all visits to the index page end up being registered incorrectly.

There are two index pages:

- **http://domain.co.uk/en/**
- **http://domain.co.uk/pl/**

Visiting http://domain.co.uk redirects to one of the above. Anyway when I visit either of those two, analytics adds the domain name at the end for some reason, so if I visit http://domain.co.uk/en/ GA registers http://domain.co.uk/en/domain.co.uk.

I tried adding canonical (with the actual address) to the index page, but it changed nothing. Note this problem only happens on the index page, other pages are registered correctly in GA. Anyone got an idea what could possibly make analytics save those addresses incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barnettt's suggestion made me (and my boss) look through the Analitics' settings some more and I think I figured it out. Someone set **default page** (view settings) to **domain.co.uk**. The value is obviously incorrect, but more interesting is the fact that it was probably there from the start, yet the incorrect page started getting registered only a few months ago.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to reproduce this error, the only way is via "RequestURI" filter. Is there any chance you have such, it could be the reason for this.